# Add an alertcontroller in a global swift file?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a alert box inside the swift file other than the `UIViewController` file. but I could not create it.

```
extension NetworkManager {

    func showAlert(message: String,from:UIViewController, title: String = "") {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        from.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

the above code is for implementing alertcontroller but I don't know how to pass the view controller I need to present so need assistance.

Answer (score 3):

```
extension UIViewController {
     func showAlert(message: String, title: String = "") {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }    
}
```

and use like this

```
from.showAlert(message:"Your message", title: "Title")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Utilities` class in your project.

```
class Utilities {

    static func showSimpleAlert(OnViewController vc: UIViewController, Message message: String) {

        //Create alertController object with specific message
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "App Name", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

        //Add OK button to alert and dismiss it on action
        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in

            alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alertController.addAction(alertAction)

        //Show alert to user
        vc.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Utilities.showSimpleAlert(OnViewController: self, Message: "Some message")
```

Comment: This func may be `static`, to avoid creating an useless object on every call

Comment: Yes..!!  That's the best option. Answer updated. Thanks...!!!

Comment: well if you have chosen a class for that, make it `final`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the extension I made. It allows to show either **Alert** or **Action sheet** and allows multiple actions "from the box"

```
extension UIViewController {

    func presentAlert(title: String?, message: String, actions: UIAlertAction..., animated: Bool = true) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        actions.forEach { alert.addAction($0) }
        self.present(alert, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }

    func presentActionSheet(title: String?, message: String, actions: UIAlertAction..., animated: Bool = true) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        actions.forEach { alert.addAction($0) }
        self.present(alert, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
    let delete = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { _ in /* Your code here */})
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)

    presentAlert(title: .albumPreferencesDeleteAlertTitle, message: "Very important message", actions: delete, cancel)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the more generalise method to show alert on view controller

```
func showAlert(msg: String, inViewController vc: UIViewController, actions: [UIAlertAction]? = nil, type: UIAlertControllerStyle = .alert, title: String = kAppName) {

    let alertType: UIAlertControllerStyle = .alert
    let alertTitle = kAppName
    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: msg, preferredStyle: alertType)

    if let actions = actions {

        for action in actions {
            alertVC.addAction(action)
        }

    } else {

        let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertVC.addAction(actionCancel)
    }

    vc.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Usage**

```
AppUtilities.showAlert(msg: "Test msg", inViewController: self) //for alert
AppUtilities.showAlert(msg: "Test msg", inViewController: self, actions: [okAction, cancelAction]) //for alert
AppUtilities.showAlert(msg: "Test Msg", inViewController: self, type: .actionSheet) //shows action sheet
```

You can add this function in extension or create a separate utility class as you want.